# C++ i can't run a program. No se ejecuta el programa

Tags: c++

My problem is very simple, I can't run the program in C++.
Its a simple program, like a "Hello World!", compile fine but when I want make it run just appear a black screen of the console, nothing more.

EDIT
My system is Windows 7 (64 bits)

I tried in Visual Studio 2013, in QtCreator, and in NetBeans 8.0.2 and the problem its the same, BUT I DISCOVER THIS... the old projects (code that I did before and run well) still run fine, only new projects can't run.

Edit:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

cout << "HOLA  MUNDO" << endl;
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: What compiler are you using? What OS are you using? How are you running the program?

Comment: Thanks for reply.
But, whatever, with this code or with other, it's the same, never execute.

Comment: Try to add `cin.get()` before `return 0;` Or, better, `cin.ignore();`

Comment: I compiled your code in Dev C++, using GCC 4.9.2 compiler and it runs perfectly.
HOLA MUNDO is printed on the screen. What compiler are you using?
Which OS?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit.
I don't know what compiler im using.
I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I try. i have the same problem, just appear the console in black.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal. It happens if you run your program 'inside' Visual Studio IDE:

- a console window is opened;
- your program is ran;
- the console window is closed.

Your program runs fine, only the above happens too fast.

There are three solutions I can think of:

1. If you are in debug mode, **place a breakpoint** (F9, usually) at last line and launch the program (F5). Once the breakpoint is reached, switch to console window, then back to IDE and press F5 to end the program.
2. Run your program in a **console window** (START+R, CMD, ENTER).
3. **Change your code**: add `cin.ignore();` before `return 0;`. The program will wait for you to enter something before it ends.

Comment: Hello, thank for reply.
1) The program never does launch and the IDE stops working.
2) Executed the program in a console and nothing happens.
3) I changed the code but the problem persist.

Comment: Try to recall what changes you did to your system. You may also try to sign in as administrator or reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: I solved, was the antivirus!!! I stopped and then worked it.
Thanks you all for your help.